# Mapping tibble columns specified by substrings

Tags: r, mapping

I have a tibble with a list of stocks, each has a sector ids, each sector is a string with 8 characters (it is a level 4 GICS sector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard):

```
tabl <- tibble(Stock=c("A","B","C","D"), SectorId=c("30101010", "30101010", "20103015", "55102010"))
```

I also have a tibble that map a SectorId to a ClusterId:

```
map_tabl <- tibble(ClusterId=c("C1","C1", "C2","C3"), SectorId=c("3010", "3020", "201030", "551020"))
```

Note that in the cluster mapping we have a mix of sectors defined on the 4 different levels (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard), i.e. Sector "3010" contains sector "30101010". The first 2 characters correspond to Level 1, the first 4 to Level 2, the first 6 to Level 3, and the 8 characters to Level 4. So for example in this case "30101010" belongs to the higher level sector "3010", which is in ClusterId="C1". Note that "30101010" is not specified at all in map_tabl, so probably I should use a function that look at substrings, like grepl.

The resulting tibble should be:

```
tibble(Stock=c("A","B","C","D"), SectorId=c("30101010", "30101010", "20103015", "55102010"), ClusterId=c("C1", "C1", "C2", "C3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can use a regex (fuzzy) join for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin) # regex_left_join
map_tabl %>%
  mutate(SectorId = paste0("^", SectorId)) %>%
  regex_left_join(tabl, ., by = "SectorId")
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Stock SectorId.x ClusterId SectorId.y
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     
# 1 A     30101010   C1        ^3010     
# 2 B     30101010   C1        ^3010     
# 3 C     20103015   C2        ^201030   
# 4 D     55102010   C3        ^551020
```

`fuzzyjoin` always keeps both versions of the join variables around, it's easy enough to `mutate(SectorId = SectorId.x, SectorId.x = NULL, SectorId.y = NULL)` or similar (choosing `select(-SectorId.x)`, etc, also works).

The precondition of `SectorId` to add the `^` is so that the matches only occur at the beginning of the string.

This does *not* attempt to limit the number of matches, so if there are multiple rows in `map_tabl` that might match an entry (e.g., `SectorId=c("3010", "301010")`), then you will need to define a clear way to choose which of these to retain. For this, I assume either `Stock` is a unique ID of sorts, or if not then you can add one yourself to make sure you end the operation with the same rows (no dupes) as before the join.